# how to print 3x3 array in python?

Tags: python

I need to print a 3 x 3 array for a game called TicTackToe.py. I know we can print stuff from a list in a horizontal or vertical way by using

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
# VERTICAL PRINTING 
for item in listA:
        print item
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

or

```
# HORIZONTAL  PRINTING
for item in listA:
        print item,
```

Output:

```
a b c d e f g h i j
```

How can I print a mix of both, e.g. printing a 3x3 box
like

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the items, and print a newline only every third item:

```
for index, item in enumerate('abcdefghij', start=1):
    print item,
    if not index % 3:
        print
```

Output:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j
```

`enumerate` starts counting from zero by default, so I set `start=1`.

As @arekolek comments, if you're using Python 3, or have imported the print function from the future for Python 2, you can specify the line ending all in one go, instead of the two steps above:

```
for index, item in enumerate('abcdefghij', start=1):
    print(item, end=' ' if index % 3 else '\n')
```

Comment: Amazing that there are specific "recipes" (as Padraic shows), but I think your path is much better -- because **your code is simple and its effect obvious** to even a Python novice (that is, without knowledge of (rare?) imports).

Comment: This could also be rewritten using the print function as `for i, v in enumerate('abcdefghij', 1): print(v, end=' ' if i % 3 else '\n')`.

Comment: You could also avoid `start=1` and use `'\n' if i%3 == 2 else ' '` or `' ' if i%3 < 2 else '\n'`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I think that's less comprehensible.

Comment: To me they are the same. BTW: I don't see the point of calling `list` when iterating over that string... Is it just because the OP uses a list?

Comment: @Bakuriu I was thinking it would help OP realise they pass their list to enumerate. I've removed it now though, as I think it's self evident (I hope!), and as you point out, it's redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the logic from the [grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

print("\n".join(map(" ".join, zip(*[iter(listA)] * 3))))
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

If you don't want to lose elements use `izip_longest` with an empty string as a fillvalue:

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
from itertools import izip_longest

print("\n".join(map(" ".join, izip_longest(*[iter(listA)] * 3,fillvalue=""))))
```

Which differs in that it keeps the j:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j
```

You can put the logic in a function and call it when you want to print, passing in whatever values you want.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def print_matrix(m,n, fill):
    print( "\n".join(map(" ".join, izip_longest(*[iter(m)] * n, fillvalue=fill))))
```

Or without itertools just chunk and join, you can also take a `sep` arg to use as the delimiter:

```
def print_matrix(m,n, sep):
    print( "\n".join(map("{}".format(sep).join, (m[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(m), n)))))
```

You just need to pass the list and the size for each row:

```
In [13]: print_matrix(listA, 3, " ")
a b c
d e f
g h i
j

In [14]: print_matrix(listA, 3, ",")
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
j

In [15]: print_matrix(listA, 4, ",")
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j

In [16]: print_matrix(listA, 4, ";")
a;b;c;d
e;f;g;h
i;j
```

Answer (score 8):

A simple approach would be to use the modulo operator:

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

count = 0

for item in listA:
    if not count % 3:
        print
    print item,
    count += 1
```

As pointed out by Peter Wood, you can use the enumerator operator, to avoid the count variable:

```python
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

listB = enumerate(listA)
for item in listB:
    if not item[0] % 3:
        print
    print item[1],
```

Comment: Why not use [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to do the counting for you?

Comment: That is totally functional but the most awkward use of `enumerate` I've seen. Also, it's the enumerate function, not the enumerator operator. Your version rhymes better though.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the two answers given here is to use something that does the formatting for you, like numpy. This is an external dependency you might not want in general, but if you're already storing things in grids/matrices, it can be a logical choice:

```
from numpy import array
str(array(listA).reshape((3,3)))
```

Put it in an array, reshape it in your favourite (compatible) shape, and make it a string. Couldn't be more intuitive!

Comment: "Couldn't be more intuitive!" Really?

Comment: @MadPhysicist syntactically, I don't think so (well, maybe I'm a little hyperbolic). Take a flat array and reshape it: that makes sense to me. If I saw this I would immediately know what it's doing: if I saw Padraic's answer with join->map->join->zip->iter, it would take a second to figure out what we were doing. That answer is awesome, don't get me wrong, but I think this is a good option too :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist if you're going by "intuitive in terms of what someone new to python would be familiar with" then it seems like the ones using modulus are about as good as you'll get

Comment: I agree about it being a good option. My initial reflex was to mention numpy as well when I saw matrix in the title. However, I don't think that adding numpy into the mix is optimal for a guy just trying to figure out how print works. I also wish beginners didn't have to learn print so early, especially the Python2 statement, but that's another story.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that all sounds fair

Answer (score 4):

You could use the format method of the string object:

```
for i in range(3):
    print "{} {} {}".format(*listA[3*i:3*i+3])
```

Also, instead of multiplying the index by 3 at every iteration, you can just take steps of three elements through the list:

```
for i in range(0, len(listA), 3):
    print "{} {} {}".format(*listA[i:i+3])
```

Comment: In Python 3: `for i in range(0, len(listA), 3): print(*listA[i:i+3])`

Comment: @arekolek, that would work fine in py2.7 as well. It works the same whether you step every three or multiply by three. I chose the latter, but your syntax does look cleaner.

Comment: I was actually thinking about the print function when I included the disclaimer. But of course you could [import it from the future](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html). BTW you can feel free to incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: @arekolek. I may as well.

Answer (score 1):

One method which have not been mentioned: Get the slice of the list mathematically and `print` by the slice of the list.

In `Python 2.x`:

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
val = (len(listA) + 2) // 3
for i in range(val):
    print(' '.join(listA[i*3:(i+1)*3]))
```

In `Python 3.x`:

```
listA=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
val = (len(listA) + 2) // 3
for i in range(val):
    print(*listA[i*3:(i+1)*3], sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join(' '*(n%3!=0)+l+'\n'*(n%3==2) for n,l in enumerate(listA))

a b c
d e f
g h i
j
```

Python is awesome.

Comment: Despite Python being awesome this question is not an obfuscated code tournament

Comment: Fine line between "obfuscated" and "beautifully succinct", wouldn't you say?

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: The output has an extra space at the beginning of each line.

Comment: The output now has an extra space at the end of each line

Comment: No charge for the space.

Comment: I think, if it's not clear what errors are in the code, and it takes a number of attempts to get it almost right, it's not beautiful, and it's not succinct (clearly expressed).

Comment: You're the only one saying there are errors. Beethoven laboured endlessly to get his music right. But I'm glad my little piece of code has inspired you. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**An easy solution**
#The end="" will print the values in the same line and the empty print() will make the control move to the immediately next line.
#Don't use "\n", for it will create an empty line between the rows!

```
s = []
for i in range(3):
    s.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print(s[i][j],"",end="")
    print()
```