# how can I print such as this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

I want to print the first n data of a list in the first line with one space between every data, and second n data of a list in the second line with one space between every data and etc
for example in List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] i want to print the data of this List in 3 line such as this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

what should I do?

Comment: This is clearly homework. In order to ask something here you need to provide your attempt first. So try it out and see what you get before posting it here

Comment: Hi Kourosh, this is not a place where you come and ask these homework questions. Attempt it first, if you are not able to do even after that, come with the approaches you tried, then only it would be a real help to you. You would be able to know where you went wrong.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print 3x3 array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903828/how-to-print-3x3-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I'd slice the list up to chunks the size of `n`, and then join each sublist on a space:

```
def printInChunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(len(lst) // n):
        print(' '.join(str(x) for x in lst[i * n : (i + 1) * n]))

# From the example above:
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3
```

Comment: The Q's been tagged Python 3.x... so this'll cause a SyntaxError... and could take advantage of unpacking the elements into the `print()` function as well...

Comment: @JonClements arg, missed the tag. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for index, item in enumerate(lista, start = 1): 
    if index % 3 == 0:
        print(item)
    else:
        print(item, end='')
```

Output :

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 three.py 
> 123
> 456
> 789
> ```

If you want that space gap just add `''`

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for index, item in enumerate(lista, start = 1): 
    if index % 3 == 0:
        print(item,'')
    else:
        print(item,'', end='')
```

Output :

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 three.py 
> 1 2 3 
> 4 5 6 
> 7 8 9
> ```